# Dynamically load sagas for code splitting in redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to integrate redux-saga into my react app. I am currently code splitting reducers by dynamically injecting it using replaceReducer when correct route is hit.I am adding a code snippet.

```
reducerRegistry.setChangeListener(reducers => {
    store.replaceReducer(combine(reducers));
});
```

I want to do the same with sagas but couldn't figure out a way to dynamically inject saga.

Comment: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/76#issuecomment-181541404 ... also there are several libs to help with redux code-splitting in general, see https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting#libraries-and-frameworks

Answer (score 4):

I tried to implement it like below and it seems to work.

```
export class SagaRegistry {
  constructor() {
    this._emitChange = null;
    this._sagas = {};
  }

  getSagas() {
    return { ...this._sagas };
  }

  register(name, saga) {
    if (this._sagas[name]) {
      return;
    }
    this._sagas = { ...this._sagas, [name]: saga };
    if (this._emitChange) {
      this._emitChange(saga);
    }
  }

  setChangeListener(listener) {
    this._emitChange = listener;
  }
}

const sagaRegistry = new SagaRegistry();
export default sagaRegistry;
```

And run saga like this.

```
sagaRegistry.setChangeListener(saga => {
  sagaMiddleware.run(saga);
});
```

Comment: I've used this pattern before, it works well for both reducers and sagas. One pitfall though is that it's possible for your sagas to be imported first during bundling, and it will register before the saga middleware was added to the store. To solve this you can change the `setChangeListener()` and add this line after setting the listener: `this._sagas.forEach((saga) => this._emitChange(saga));`